# How to compare data frame values to column names and set to NA for multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   YEAR X1990_lu X2000_lu X2010_lu     soil    water
1  1990 215.0310 215.0310 215.0310 3.588198 5.287578
2  2007 415.3221 415.3221 415.3221 8.094746 5.788305
3  1994 263.5908 263.5908 263.5908 4.680792 5.408977
4  2010 453.2070 453.2070 453.2070 8.947157 5.883017
5  2012 476.1869 476.1869 476.1869 9.464206 5.940467
6  1981 118.2226 118.2226 118.2226 1.410008 5.045556
7  1998 311.2422 311.2422 311.2422 5.752949 5.528105
8  2011 456.9676 456.9676 456.9676 9.031771 5.892419
9  1999 320.5740 320.5740 320.5740 5.962915 5.551435
10 1995 282.6459 282.6459 282.6459 5.109533 5.456615
11 2013 482.7333 482.7333 482.7333 9.611500 5.956833
12 1995 281.3337 281.3337 281.3337 5.080007 5.453334
13 2003 371.0283 371.0283 371.0283 7.098136 5.677571
14 2000 329.0534 329.0534 329.0534 6.153701 5.572633
15 1983 141.1699 141.1699 141.1699 1.926322 5.102925
```

I need to set any column with `_lu` in the name to NA if the corresponding numeric part of the column name is greater than the value of YEAR for that row. I can do this for each individual column using the code below, where I extract the numeric part of the `_lu` column names and make a numeric vector to compare to YEAR. But, can this be done for all the columns by using apply or possibly map statements?

```
## make example data
set.seed(123)
soil <- runif(15,1,10)
set.seed(123)
water <- runif(15,5,6)
set.seed(123)
X1990_lu <- runif(15,100,500)
set.seed(123)
X2000_lu <- runif(15,100,500)
set.seed(123)
X2010_lu <- runif(15,100,500)
set.seed(123)
YEAR <- as.integer(runif(15,1980,2015))

data <- data.frame(YEAR, X1990_lu, X2000_lu, X2010_lu, soil, water)

# extract the column indices of the landuse columns
lucolsind <- grep("_lu", names(data))
# remove the x from each landuse column name
colnames(data)[lucolsind] <- substring(names(data[,lucolsind]), 2)
# get the column names
lucolnms <- names(data[,lucolsind])
# get the column names as a split list
lucolnms_lst <- strsplit(names(data[,lucolsind]), c("_"))
# extract just the year indicator
luyears <- unlist(lapply(lucolnms_lst, `[[`, 1))

# set the first LU column to NA where year is less than the lu year
data[,lucolsind[1]] <- ifelse(data$YEAR < luyears[1], NA, data[,lucolsind[1]])
```

Here is how it looks after processing just the first `_lu` column

```
   YEAR  1990_lu  2000_lu  2010_lu     soil    water
1  1990 215.0310 215.0310 215.0310 3.588198 5.287578
2  2007 415.3221 415.3221 415.3221 8.094746 5.788305
3  1994 263.5908 263.5908 263.5908 4.680792 5.408977
4  2010 453.2070 453.2070 453.2070 8.947157 5.883017
5  2012 476.1869 476.1869 476.1869 9.464206 5.940467
6  1981       NA 118.2226 118.2226 1.410008 5.045556
7  1998 311.2422 311.2422 311.2422 5.752949 5.528105
8  2011 456.9676 456.9676 456.9676 9.031771 5.892419
9  1999 320.5740 320.5740 320.5740 5.962915 5.551435
10 1995 282.6459 282.6459 282.6459 5.109533 5.456615
11 2013 482.7333 482.7333 482.7333 9.611500 5.956833
12 1995 281.3337 281.3337 281.3337 5.080007 5.453334
13 2003 371.0283 371.0283 371.0283 7.098136 5.677571
14 2000 329.0534 329.0534 329.0534 6.153701 5.572633
15 1983       NA 141.1699 141.1699 1.926322 5.102925
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `sapply` on column's ending with `_lu`. This can be achieved as:

```
df[,grepl("_lu$",names(df))] <- 
  sapply(grep("_lu$",names(df), value = TRUE), function(x){
  # Convert column names to numeric and compare with YEAR value of that row
  x = ifelse(df$YEAR < as.numeric(gsub("X(\\d+)_lu","\\1",x)), NA, df[,x])
  x
})

df
#    YEAR X1990_lu X2000_lu X2010_lu     soil    water
# 1  1990 215.0310       NA       NA 3.588198 5.287578
# 2  2007 415.3221 415.3221       NA 8.094746 5.788305
# 3  1994 263.5908       NA       NA 4.680792 5.408977
# 4  2010 453.2070 453.2070 453.2070 8.947157 5.883017
# 5  2012 476.1869 476.1869 476.1869 9.464206 5.940467
# 6  1981       NA       NA       NA 1.410008 5.045556
# 7  1998 311.2422       NA       NA 5.752949 5.528105
# 8  2011 456.9676 456.9676 456.9676 9.031771 5.892419
# 9  1999 320.5740       NA       NA 5.962915 5.551435
# 10 1995 282.6459       NA       NA 5.109533 5.456615
# 11 2013 482.7333 482.7333 482.7333 9.611500 5.956833
# 12 1995 281.3337       NA       NA 5.080007 5.453334
# 13 2003 371.0283 371.0283       NA 7.098136 5.677571
# 14 2000 329.0534 329.0534       NA 6.153701 5.572633
# 15 1983       NA       NA       NA 1.926322 5.102925
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"   YEAR X1990_lu X2000_lu X2010_lu     soil    water
1  1990 215.0310 215.0310 215.0310 3.588198 5.287578
2  2007 415.3221 415.3221 415.3221 8.094746 5.788305
3  1994 263.5908 263.5908 263.5908 4.680792 5.408977
4  2010 453.2070 453.2070 453.2070 8.947157 5.883017
5  2012 476.1869 476.1869 476.1869 9.464206 5.940467
6  1981 118.2226 118.2226 118.2226 1.410008 5.045556
7  1998 311.2422 311.2422 311.2422 5.752949 5.528105
8  2011 456.9676 456.9676 456.9676 9.031771 5.892419
9  1999 320.5740 320.5740 320.5740 5.962915 5.551435
10 1995 282.6459 282.6459 282.6459 5.109533 5.456615
11 2013 482.7333 482.7333 482.7333 9.611500 5.956833
12 1995 281.3337 281.3337 281.3337 5.080007 5.453334
13 2003 371.0283 371.0283 371.0283 7.098136 5.677571
14 2000 329.0534 329.0534 329.0534 6.153701 5.572633
15 1983 141.1699 141.1699 141.1699 1.926322 5.102925",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: How does `gsub("X(\\d+)_lu","\\1",x)` access the column names? Since `df[,2]` just returns a vector of the column values and not the name.

Comment: @user29609 `names(df)` is passed to `sapply`. Now the `function(x)` gets the column name in `x` and usages that in `ifelse` condition.

Answer (score 0):

A 'tidyverse' approach that uses reshaping in order to compare the values of interest with the corresponding date in the column name row by row:

```
dt = read.table(text = "
YEAR X1990_lu X2000_lu X2010_lu     soil    water
1  1990 215.0310 215.0310 215.0310 3.588198 5.287578
2  2007 415.3221 415.3221 415.3221 8.094746 5.788305
3  1994 263.5908 263.5908 263.5908 4.680792 5.408977
4  2010 453.2070 453.2070 453.2070 8.947157 5.883017
5  2012 476.1869 476.1869 476.1869 9.464206 5.940467
6  1981 118.2226 118.2226 118.2226 1.410008 5.045556
7  1998 311.2422 311.2422 311.2422 5.752949 5.528105
8  2011 456.9676 456.9676 456.9676 9.031771 5.892419
9  1999 320.5740 320.5740 320.5740 5.962915 5.551435
10 1995 282.6459 282.6459 282.6459 5.109533 5.456615
11 2013 482.7333 482.7333 482.7333 9.611500 5.956833
12 1995 281.3337 281.3337 281.3337 5.080007 5.453334
13 2003 371.0283 371.0283 371.0283 7.098136 5.677571
14 2000 329.0534 329.0534 329.0534 6.153701 5.572633
15 1983 141.1699 141.1699 141.1699 1.926322 5.102925
", header=T)

library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  gather(var,value,-YEAR) %>%  
  mutate(value = ifelse(YEAR < as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", var)) & !is.na(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", var))), NA, value)) %>%
  group_by(YEAR, var) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  spread(var, value) %>% 
  select(-id) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 15 x 6
#   YEAR  soil water X1990_lu X2000_lu X2010_lu
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1  1981  1.41  5.05      NA       NA       NA 
# 2  1983  1.93  5.10      NA       NA       NA 
# 3  1990  3.59  5.29     215.      NA       NA 
# 4  1994  4.68  5.41     264.      NA       NA 
# 5  1995  5.11  5.46     283.      NA       NA 
# 6  1995  5.08  5.45     281.      NA       NA 
# 7  1998  5.75  5.53     311.      NA       NA 
# 8  1999  5.96  5.55     321.      NA       NA 
# 9  2000  6.15  5.57     329.     329.      NA 
# 10  2003  7.10  5.68     371.     371.      NA 
# 11  2007  8.09  5.79     415.     415.      NA 
# 12  2010  8.95  5.88     453.     453.     453.
# 13  2011  9.03  5.89     457.     457.     457.
# 14  2012  9.46  5.94     476.     476.     476.
# 15  2013  9.61  5.96     483.     483.     483.
```